# Invalid format for createdBy in SpringBoot Auditable

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I implemented SpringBoot Auditable and everything is working fine except the createdBy is giving timestamp.

Here is my Auditable class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Auditable {

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @CreatedBy
    private ObjectId createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private ObjectId updatedBy;

}
```

And here is my AuditorAwareImpl class:

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<ObjectId> {

    @Override
    public Optional<ObjectId> getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        ObjectId userId = null;
        if (authentication != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

            userId = new ObjectId(userDetails.getId());
        }
        return Optional.of(userId);
    }
}
```

It's(ObjectId) saving fine to DB. But when I retrieve that record, I'm getting createdBy as different format instead of ObjectId:

[image]

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this bean convert the ObjectId to String.

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0.rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

And Add the bean

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DivisionServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DivisionServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
  
  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer() {
    return builder -> builder.serializerByType(ObjectId.class, new ToStringSerializer());
  }  
  
}
```